# Can't perform click action on an element with a locator in Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am trying to go to this simple webpage and perform a click action on an element. It fails even though I'm using unique selectors (I tried different Xpath and css selectors). By debugging it points to the locator's element still cant perform click action on it, showing error  `` Test timeout of 60000ms exceeded.- locator.click: Target closed` waiting for the locator ``

Here is the code:

```
test.only('click on date picker', async ({page})=>{
  await page.goto('https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/datepicker/#Simple%20Date%20Picker')

  const clickFirst = page.locator("input[class='hasDatepicker']")

  await clickFirst.click()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the id to target the date picker.

If I look at the page something like this should work:

`await page.locator("#datepicker").click();`

The [playwright extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-playwright.playwright#pick-locators) for Vs Code also offers an option to pick locators from a website, this makes it easier to find a fitting selector.

Answer (score -1):

The element you want is in a frame, so locate the frame first:

```js
import {test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.30.0

test.only("click on date picker", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto(
    "https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/datepicker/#Simple%20Date%20Picker"
  );
  await page
    .frameLocator(".demo-frame")
    .first()
    .locator("#datepicker")
    .click();
});
```

Attribute selectors like `input[class='hasDatepicker']` should be avoided, because they're overly strict, forcing an exact match in a specific order. Your selector fails on elements with additional classes beyond the `hasDatepicker` class. Almost always, use `input.hasDatepicker` instead, although here, we have an id, so prefer that as I've done above.